# Count of Type using if then else

Tags: sql, if-statement, count, nested, case

I have this following table in which i need to count `type = D` as **1**, but if that ID ends with R then it should count as **0**.

ID 123 always starts with D then it can be R then can be D or A.

```
 ID         Decision Dt       Type/Status
 123        1/15/2014          D     
 123        1/20/2014          A  
 123        1/15/2014          R
```

i have written SQL as `sum(if(type=d)then 1 else 0 end)`. I am getting the right count until `type/status` is R. And this is the only ID in DB which ends with status R and not moved to D. I need help in writing the sql.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: which database you are using and how to find **ID ends with R**

Comment: @NoDisplayName - i am using Teradatabase

Comment: @NoDisplayName - those IDs can be disposed (D) and R(Reverse Disposed).. and it can be seen based on Decision Date..

Comment: So in your case you would count 1, because the latest date for ID 123 is January 20 with type A. If that record wouldn't exist, R would be on the same day as D and on the last day for ID 123. Count 0 or 1 then? Can there be more than one D and R? If so, do we still only look at the last record and check for R, and would we count Ds or is it always 1 no matter how many Ds?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - in this case we are only counting number of Ds even if the latest date is A(We can ignore As). We can have more than 1 Ds and Rs for each ID.   ID always starts with D and  ends with either R or A, in this case it has both the status(R and D) on same Day so its ending with R and count should be 0. For example if it has D--> R--> D then count should be 2 and if we have only D--> A then count should be 1 and if we have D-->R-->A Then count should be 0 (since its ending with R ) we always look at the last status of that ID ignoring As

Comment: I Even tried the following -

sum(case when type =D then 
case when type = R then 0
when type = D then 0
end

when type = D
then 1 else 0

end)


RESULT- i am still getting the count as 1

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in all records with type D and R. You also need to mark the last record somehow. This can be done with RANK. Rank 1 for the latest entry per ID.

Then group by ID and see if there is a last record with type R for that ID. If so the result is 0, else count type D.

```
select 
  id,
  case when max(case when last_is_one = 1 and type = 'R' then 1 end) = 1 then
    0
  else
    count(case when type = 'D' then 1 end)
  end as d_count
from
(
  select  
    id,
    type,
    rank() over (partition by id order by decision_dt desc) as last_is_one
  from mytable 
  where type in ('D','R')
) d_and_r
group by id;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48c820/3.

Comment: i tried your query i am still getting count  D as 1 and RD as 0 and dates are  1/15/2014 for both D and RD

Comment: Strange, the query should do what you want. I've added an SQL fiddle where you see it work. I also corrected minor errors (a missing CASE keyword and a name for the derived table that some dbms need), but you've already spotted them; otherwise you could not have run the query. So please have a look at the fiddle to check again.

Comment: hey i figured that out.. i was also including decision dt in select and group by thats why i was not able to get it. But thank you Thorsten Kettner.